# mySQL - Select block of rows where 'X'=0 and difference of datetime to last row of 'X'>0 is greater than...?

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have a locations table with `IMEI - VARCHAR (15), speed - INT, datetime DATETIME` ordered by `datetime`. I need to find all block of rows (1 or more) where speed = 0 and datetime difference to last row of speed > 0 is greater than 15 minutes.

My best so far is this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations L1 WHERE speed = 0 AND timestampdiff(MINUTE,datetime,(SELECT datetime FROM locations WHERE SPEED > 0 AND datetime<L1.datetime ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1)) > 15
```

But it gives no results.

Here is my sqlfiddle for an example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46061c

EDIT: Edited link above

Comment: nor should it. you can't use limits in subqueries.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you have any idea about how I can 'solve' this?

Comment: @marcb ? So you mean you can't do something like `Select * from 
(select * from mytable 
order by string DESC 
limit 2) x order by string;`

Comment: hmm. actually it's on an `IN(...)` where limits aren't allowed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html